# Get only fields with datatype int in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, pyqgis-3

With the following line of code, I get a list of field names for the layer `layer`.

```
 fields = layer.fields().names()
```

However, I would like to get only those fields with the datatype `Integer`. How would I do that? I checked the class [QgsFields](https://qgis.org/pyqgis/master/core/QgsFields.html) but I don't see a function that relates to the datatype. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By type name (`typeName()`):

```
int_types = ["Integer", "Integer64"]
int_fields = [field for field in iface.activeLayer().fields() if field.typeName() in int_types]
```

OR by type number (`type()`):

```
int_types = [2, 4] # 2: Integer, 4: Integer64
int_fields = [field for field in iface.activeLayer().fields() if field.type() in int_types]
```

Type of some fields may be `Integer64`. `Integer64` equals `QVariant.LongLong` actually, but it could be considered as integer.

Comment: Do you know where I find which field.types() are which, without using field.typeName()?

Comment: @BERA "*Field types vary depending on the data source. Examples are char, int, double, blob, geometry, etc*" (from [Docs](https://qgis.org/api/classQgsField.html#a1bc56243420f480306fee9ae69773b31)). I found [QVariant Types](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/kernel/qvariant.h.html#QVariant::Type). And [some types](https://qgis.org/api/qgis_8cpp_source.html#l00219) which are, I guess, probably available for spatial data formats.

Comment: @BERA (Type name -> Type number)... bool -> 1... integer, int2(16bit), int4(32bit) -> 2... int8(64bit) -> 4... double, numeric, decimal, real, double precision -> 6... string, text -> 10... date -> 14... time -> 15... datetime -> 16... Add temporary sctrach layer and try to add a new field. You will see a lot of different types of field.

Comment: Ok! Im lookning for a way in pyqgis to do what in [arcgis would be](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/field.htm): `[f for f in arcpy.ListField(feature_class) if f.type == 'String']` or list only numeric field etc. And not have to worry about Int/Int64/Int32 etc. or String/varchar/??? etc. There seems to be so many different field types in pyqgis

Answer (score 8):

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
intfields = [f for f in layer.fields() if f.typeName().startswith('Int')]
print(intfields)
```

Found typeName [here](https://qgis.org/api/qgsfield_8h_source.html#l00057)